# SQL Select by condition on a integer field

Tags: sql, select, conditional-statements

I have an integer column in my table. It is `product id` and has values like

```
112233001  
112233002  
113311001  
225577001
```

This numbering (AABBCCDDD) is formed of 4 parts:

```
AA : first level category  
BB : second level category  
CC : third level category  
DDD : counter
```

I want to check condition in my `SELECT` statement to select rows that for example have BB = 33 and AA = 11

Please help

Comment: I think you are looking for a bitwise and.  See:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/360844/mysql-bitwise-operations-bloom-filter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM YOURTABLE

WHERE 

substr(PRODUCT_ID, 3, 2)='33'
AND
substr(PRODUCT_ID, 1, 2)='11'
```

OR

```
SELECT * FROM YOURTABLE

WHERE 

PRODUCT_ID LIKE '11%33%'
```

**and yes in short you have to convert to string**

[reference of substr](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions162.htm)

**Purpose**

The SUBSTR functions return a portion of char, beginning at character position, substring_length characters long. SUBSTR calculates lengths using characters as defined by the input character set. SUBSTRB uses bytes instead of characters. SUBSTRC uses Unicode complete characters. SUBSTR2 uses UCS2 code points. SUBSTR4 uses UCS4 code points.

```
If position is 0, then it is treated as 1.

If position is positive, then Oracle Database counts from the beginning of char to find the first character.

If position is negative, then Oracle counts backward from the end of char.

If substring_length is omitted, then Oracle returns all characters to the end of char. If substring_length is less than 1, then Oracle returns null.
```

char can be any of the datatypes `CHAR, VARCHAR2, NCHAR, NVARCHAR2, CLOB, or NCLOB`. Both position and substring_length `must be of datatype NUMBER`, or any datatype that can be implicitly converted to NUMBER, and must resolve to an integer. The return value is the same datatype as char. Floating-point numbers passed as arguments to SUBSTR are automatically converted to integers.

Comment: as the '11' and '13' are examples, I can not use the second Select statement, but the first one is exactly what I wanted. thanks!

Comment: Is there any need to convert my product_id to string? or the substr, can do it for me?

Answer (score 4):

Would this suffice:

```
select x from table where field >= 113300000 and field < 113400000
```

Answer (score 1):

```
          Select field from table where substr(field,,) = value
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems like it could work. Otherwise you may have to cast them as strings and parse the values out that you need which would make your queries much slower.

```
SELECT * 
    FROM table t
WHERE t.field >= 113300000
AND t.field < 113400000
```

Answer (score 0):

u need to use `_` wildcard char -

```
SELECT * 
FROM TABLE
WHERE
FIELD LIKE '1133_____'
```

here, each `_` is for one char. So you need to put the same number of `_` to keep the length same